# Frequency Analysis Assistance

Tags: python, frequency, analysis, frequency-analysis

Basically, I've been assigned a task to count how many times each letter in the alphabet occurs in a piece of *encrypted* text.
Once that is done, the frequency of each letter is placed in descending order.
For example [(l,2), (e,1), {h,1), (o:1)].
This I have done and it works.

Then each letter in the descending list needs to be replaced by the matching letter in this string: 'etaoinshrdlcumfwgypbvkjxqz'
This is what i'm not sure how to do.

So far I have this:

```
enc_text = input("Enter Encrypted Text: ").lower()

count = {'a':0, 'b':0, 'c':0, 'd':0, 'e':0, 'f':0, 'g':0, 'h':0, 'i':0, 'j':0, 'k':0, 'l':0, 'm':0, 'n':0, 'o':0, 'p':0, 'q':0, 'r':0, 's':0, 't':0, 'u':0, 'v':0, 'w':0, 'x':0, 'y':0, 'z':0}

for char in enc_text:
if char.isalpha():
    count[char] += 1

print(enc_text)
print(count)

def get_value(count):
    return count[1]


sorted_text = sorted(count.items(), key = get_value)


descending_text = reversed(sorted_text)
descending_text = list(descending_text)
print(descending_text)


most_frequent = {'e': 1, 't': 2, 'a': 3, 'o': 4, 'i': 5, 'n': 6, 's': 7, 'h': 8, 'r': 9, 'd': 10, 'l': 11, 'c': 12, 'u': 13, 'm': 14, 'w': 15, 'f': 16, 'g': 17, 'y': 18, 'p': 19, 'b': 20, 'v': 21, 'k': 22, 'j': 23, 'x': 24, 'q': 25, 'z': 26}


letters = list('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz')
etaoin = list('etaoinshrdlcumfwgypbvkjxqz')
```

I believe I have to loop over the text at the start and look at it letter by letter. Then each letter should be replaced by the one in the string? But i'm not sure how to implement it.

Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: for some interesting examples and library support, you might want to have a look here: https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter

Comment: Have you solved your problem? Would be nice to hear the solution :)

Answer (score 0):

You cold loop over the encrypted text and look up the character in the descending list using `list.index()` and get the corresponding character at this position from the etaoin list.

Sample:

```
decryptedChar = eatoin[descending.index(encryptedChar)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Aside from using different libraries, you have the majority of the work done. Simply create a mapping based on frequency, then replace every letter in the encrypted text with its corresponding mapped value.

```
decryption_map = {}
for index, key in enumerate(sorted(count.items(), key = get_value)):
    decryption_map[key] = etaoin[index]
print ''.join(map( lambda x : decryption_map[key], list(enc_text)))
```

Answer (score 0):

This will give you the replacement map. Continued from the last part of your code (made `etaoin` a string):

```
etaoin = "etaoinshrdlcumfwgypbvkjxqz"

rev_etaoin = etaoin[::-1]
replacement_map = sorted_text[:]
for i in range(26):
    replacement_map[i] = (sorted_text[i][0],rev_etaoin[i])
print(replacement_map)
```

Output:

```
[('c', 'z'), ('b', 'q'), ('e', 'x'), ('g', 'j'), ('f', 'k'), ('i', 'v'), ('k', 'b'), ('m', 'p'), ('l', 'y'), ('o', 'g'), ('n', 'w'), ('p', 'f'), ('u', 'm'), ('t', 'u'), ('w', 'c'), ('v', 'l'), ('x', 'd'), ('z', 'r'), ('h', 'h'), ('q', 's'), ('r', 'n'), ('y', 'i'), ('j', 'o'), ('s', 'a'), ('d', 't'), ('a', 'e')]
```

Answer (score 0):

You have the letter counts already saved to a dictionary. How about saving the ranked letters to a dictionary with the letters as keys and ranks as values.

```
rank_dict = {}
for i in range(26):
    rank_dict[sorted(count, key=count.get, reverse = True)[i]] = i+1 
print rank_dict
```

So [(l,2), (e,1), {h,1), (o:1)] would instead be rank_dict = {'l':1:, 'e':2, 'h':3, 'o':4}. 
If you then had the most frequent dict the other way round

```
freq_dict = {1: 'e', 2: 't', 3: 'a', 4: 'o', 5: 'i', 6: 'n', 7: 's', 8: 'h', 9: 'r', 10: 'd', 11: 'l', 12: 'c', 13: 'u', 14: 'm', 15: 'f', 16: 'w', 17: 'g', 18: 'y', 19: 'p', 20: 'b', 21: 'v', 22: 'k', 23: 'j', 24: 'x', 25: 'q', 26: 'z'}
```

then you could loop through the encrypted text with:

```
dec_text = ''
for char in enc_text:
    dec_text = dec_text + freq_dict[rank_dict[char]]
```

Alternatively, if you want to keep your most_frequent dict key:value the current way round, use:

```
dec_text = dec_text + [key for key in most_frequent \
                       if most_frequent[key] == rank_dict[char]]
```

Note that cases where  multiple letters occur with the same frequency are being ranked in alphabetical order by sort/sorted. If your text is long and you are just using this as a guide to decrypt substitution ciphers that's fine - but there will likely be mistakes in the decrypted text.